Can ATmega328P microcontroller work at 3.3 V with 8 MHz oscillator
I want to use ATmega328P for my project, but I saw in datasheet that to use 16 MHz oscillators. Is it possible to use 8 MHz oscillators?
Could you please direct my attention to other things that I should pay attention to when creating my PCB.

The frequency is usually picked to suit the most picky part of the product. If you for example have serial buses present, then UART is picky about baudrate accuracy and CAN is pickier still. You'd then pick a system clock which is easily divisible to clock the serial bus hardware peripheral. Usually 8/16MHz are pretty ideal for such.

Do you mean a crystal or an oscillator when you say oscillator? Although it does not change the answer in this case.

Just in case you didn't know: the ATmega328P has an internal 8MHz oscillator and doesn't require an external one at all.

@SimSon Just in case you didn't know, the internal oscilator may be unusable for anything that requires more accuracy it can provide - meaning UART or even a real time or alarm clock. With UARTs it's best to have less than 1% of tolerance and for even 1 hour per year time drift you need 0.01%

@Justme thanks for the hint, I know what you wrote. The OP on the other hand seems to be a beginner, thus my hint...

The chip is rated to run up to 10 MHz at 2.7V to 5.5V supply, so it will run at 8 MHz with 3.3V supply. This reads on page 2 of the data sheet.
Also it's a bit unclear if you mean what should you pay attention to on the schematics how to make a working board or just the PCB layout, but Atmel/Microchip has an application note on the hardware design considerations on the MCU website, which covers powering the MCU, bypass caps and crystal layout, and even some EMI and EMC concepts.

Seems you are reading a different datasheet than what was posted with the other answer?

@Lundin For sure I am. I am quoting the data sheet for the non-automotive chip, and the other answer quotes the data sheet of the automotive chip. It still does not change the fact that the chip will work fine with 8 MHz at 3.3V.

You should read chapter 8 System Clock and Clock Options of the ATmega328P Datasheet for a better understanding. Chapter 8.8 External Clock is probably your use case.
28.5.4 External Clock Drive further specifies the clock characteristics:

For VCC = 2.7..5.5 V the max frequency is rated 8 MHz, and for VCC = 4.5..5.5 V it is 16 MHz. The min rated frequency is 0 MHz for both cases.

As Jeroen3 has noted in the comments, I've referenced the automotive variant.
The Datasheet of the non-automotive version has a wider frequency range:

Nonetheless, lower frequencies are always permitted.

As for the second part of your question (which is rather broad):

"Could you please direct my attention to some other things that I should pay attention to when creating my PCB board."

In addition to reading the datasheet carefully, I would recommend checking out the documentation of any evaluation or development board.
The ATMEGA328P-XMINI for example.
ATmega328P-Xplained-Mini_Design-Documentation.zip contains valuable information, including the schematics: ATmega328P_Xplained_Mini_design_documentation_release_rev4.pdf

These numbers are conservative because they are for the automotive variant.

Hmm. Just before those tables (29.3 Speed Grades, on p.312), the datasheet says the max frequency depends on the operating voltage linearly between 2.7 V to 4.5 V, and even shows a nice graph. That would seem to say the chip can run up to 13.33 MHz @ 3.3 V.

@ilkkachu You're right, that graph does indicate 13.33 MHz @ 3.3 V.
